# Grab the Id of an element using Jquery and replace the value within a[href*='#'] with that Id

Tags: jquery, html

I'm building a one-page portfolio site which has a fixed vertical header where I want each heading to highlight as I scroll down on to related section of the page.

```
<div class="vert-nav">
        <ul>
            <li id="logo"><a id="home-link" href="#home-wrapper" ><img id="logowt" src="img/logo.png" alt="flamin_logo"/></a></li>

            <li><a id="about-link" href="#about-wrapper"><h6>About</h6></a></li>

            <li><a id="skills-link" href="#skills-wrapper"><h6>Skills</h6></a></li>

            <li><a id="work-link" href="#work-wrapper"><h6 class="work-heading">Work</h6></a></li>

        </ul>
    </div>
```

Jquery

```
$(document).scroll(function(e){
var bound_top = $(this).scrollTop(),
    bound_bottom = bound_top + $(window).height();


$("#skills-wrapper").each(function(){


    if( 
        $(this).position().top + 300 <= bound_bottom &&
        $(this).position().top + $(this).height() >= bound_top
    ){
        $(".vert-nav a[href*='#skills-wrapper'] h6").css("color","#4d4d4d");

    }else{
        $(".vert-nav a[href*='#skills-wrapper'] h6").css("color","#BFBFBF");
    }
});
});
```

The jquery code works as it is. But I dont want to keep repeating the code for each section, instead I want to write a function which would select the Id of the element it is applied to, ex.

```
$("#skills-wrapper").each(function(){

    var thisId = $(this).attr('id')
```

and replace the a[href*='#skills-wrapper']'s value within the If statement with,

```
 $(".vert-nav a[href*='thisId'] h6").
```

so the code looks like this,

```
$(document).scroll(function(e){
var bound_top = $(this).scrollTop(),
    bound_bottom = bound_top + $(window).height();


$("#skills-wrapper").each(function(){

    var thisId = $(this).attr('id')

    if( 
        $(this).position().top + 300 <= bound_bottom &&
        $(this).position().top + $(this).height() >= bound_top
    ){
        $(".vert-nav a[href*='thisId'] h6").css("color","#4d4d4d");

    }else{
        $(".vert-nav a[href*='thisId'] h6").css("color","#BFBFBF");
    }
});
});
```

But it doesn't work! Will greatly appreciate your help! Thank you! I hope the question is clear enough!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem in your code is that you're using the string `"thisid"` and not the variable `thisId`

To get the `id`, you could just do `this.id` instead of `$(this).attr('id')` (which would also work, but is unnecessary).

And since you're matching the whole id, it will be better to use the [attribute equals selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) `[href=<id>]` rather than the [attribute contains selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/) `[href*=<id>]`

Try this:

```
$(document).scroll(function(e){
    var bound_top = $(this).scrollTop(),
        bound_bottom = bound_top + $(window).height();   
    $("#skills-wrapper").each(function(){    
       var id = this.id;    
       if(
           $(this).position().top + 300 <= bound_bottom &&
           $(this).position().top + $(this).height() >= bound_top
         ) {
            $(".vert-nav a[href='#" + id + "'] h6").css("color","#4d4d4d");    
        } else {
            $(".vert-nav a[href='#" + id + "'] h6").css("color","#BFBFBF");
        }
    });
});
```